# When dynamically linking, how does the application know which DLL file to load?

Tags: c++, gcc, dll, mingw

I wanted to build a custom zlib DLL that includes the symbol table. I used MinGW and the DLL works correctly and indeed includes the symbol table but it has to be named zlib1.dll in order to work. I want to name it zlib1-debug.dll to distinguish it from the regular stripped version. How can I inform my applications to load the renamed DLL? I don't want to use the LoadLibrary function. I also made a libz-debug.a file from the object files used to create the DLL. When I compile an example program which is supposed to use the new DLL, I pass -lz-debug to the linker. It compiles without errors, but it still wants to load "zlib1.dll" when I run it. I expected it would try to load "z-debug.dll" but apparently that's not how it works.

Answer (score 0):

When you build dynamic library, you usually get at least two files:

- library itself (for example `.dll` or `.so`)
- export library (for example `.lib` and `.a`, respectively)

Then, when you build application or other library, that utilizes it, you need to add `.lib`/`.a` file to the linker's input (dependencies) list. Now, the thing is, that name of dynamic library file (`.dll`/`.so`), that is loaded during application start is saved inside export library during linking process - that's how application "knows", which library it should load symbols from. I guess, that you have at least one of following problems:

- you didn't remove old export file from linker input, so old library is requested anyway
- you didn't add **new** export file to linker input
- you messed something up and ended with renamed export file, that refers to old library anyway

I would suggest you to:

**1.** Recompile your `zlib` with new name (`z-debug`) to make sure, that export file refers to the right library file.

**2.** Rebuild your application (it will only be re-linked), specifying new library name (so it will be linked against library with new name).

Comment: How is the dynamic library file name saved inside an .a file? Is it passed to ar? Or is it included in one of the object files?

Comment: It is saved during linking phase. All you need to do is to build properly your `DLL` with a new name and then re-link you app to make it use new library file.

Comment: I have two builds of MinGW installed. One of them is MinGW-w64. I use the same export library (libz-debug.a, compiled by myself) for both complers and use the exact same options (plus -m32 for w64), but only MinGW links correctly. The file compiled using MinGW-w64 still searches for zlib1.dll.
This is the configuration data for the "good" MinGW: http://pastebin.com/NpSUKrqM
And for the "bad" MinGW: http://pastebin.com/3RhrRjKY
I'd rather use the "bad" MinGW, because it somehow produces much smaller binaries, given the same options.